# (Admin) Collapsible blocks don't work anymore

Tags: 7

I'm currently working on a Drupal site which requires quite a lot of modules to be installed. As I progressed, I encountered several important bugs (some admin pages --eg Patterns-- not loading any more, instead displaying a critical error, etc). Among those bugs was the fact that the collapsible blocks present in various places in the admin don't work anymore: the mouse cursor doesn't change to a hand when placed upon their title, and clicking on them doesn't produce any effect. In other words, the collapsible blocks are stuck.

Because of that, I tried starting again from scratch with a clean install of Drupal 7.24 in a new separate folder and on a new database.

I was very surprised to see that **even during the Drupal install procedure** (step 4: set up database), so before Drupal is even fully installed, the collapsible block doesn't work either! (It's the block "Advanced options"). Of course there are no modules installed at that point, so it's not related to that.

I inspected the page with Firebug:

- the block stuck has the class "collapsible collapsed form-wrapper collapse-processed".
- in the header of the page, the JS file "collapse.js?v=7.24" is present.
- this JS file exists on the disc and I haven't tampered with it.

I tried restarting Firefox in Safe Mode but that didn't change anything. (I'm using Firefox 27 and it's up to date.)

Any idea what the problem might be?

**UPDATE:** I tried the installation procedure in Chrome and the collapsible blocks *do* work! So it's apparently a problem related to Firefox --and Firefox itself (as I said, I already tried Safe Mode in Firefox, so it's not caused by some 3rd-party extension). I hope it gets fixed soon.
If somebody has a solution, you're welcome to answer. :)

Comment: So what's the error in your javascript console?

Comment: @Mołot: weirdly, nothing at all... either in Firebug or in the Firefox Console (normal mode and safe mode)...

Comment: Strange. If the script is there unaltered, classes are all right and so on, there must be some error :/

Comment: I agree, but I don't know what else to test for...